# Helm dependency update when upgrading chart

Tags: redis, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've recently written a Helm chart for my application adding a redis dependency in the `requirements.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  - name: "redis"
    version: "~4.0.0"
    repository: "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/"
```

I've noticed that whenever I run my `helm upgrade` command the redis dependency gets always reinstalled, bringing redis down all the times I just need to upgrade my application.

The command I'm running is something along the lines of `helm upgrade --wait release-name ./helm-folder`

Is this behaviour expected? Isn't helm supposed to only update the application pod if there hasn't been any change to the `requirements.yaml`/`requirements.lock` file?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any specific configuration for the `redis` subchart?  (Do any of the values files you're using have a `redis:` block?)

Answer (score 0):

We saw [similar behaviour](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/pull/1351/files) - taking out the tilde locked it down. The tilde seems to mean 'this version or greater'.